# Navigation to the screen where I am now

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to update all the widgets on the screen, for this I decided to just make navigation to the screen I'm currently on. But unfortunately nothing happens. Tell me, what's the problem?
I am using the `go_router` package.

routes -

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => Splash() ,
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/home',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => const Home() ,
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/login',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => const Login() ,
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/createPinCode',
        builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) => CreatePinCode() ,
      ),
    ],
```

button -

```
onCompleted: (value) async {
                      pinCode = int.parse(value);
                      sharedPrefsSet(pinCode);
                      context.go('/createPinCode');
                    },
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Let me clarify, you want to rebuild your whole page when onCompleted function is called?

Comment: @Md.KamrulAmin Yes. Quite right. It's just that there are forms that the user fills out, after which, I want to clear them all

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clear your form textFields than rather than re-build entire page you can user `clear()` property of `TextEditingController`.

```
 TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

func clearAllData() {
  nameController.clear();
  emailController.clear();
}
```

Call this clearAllData() when user tap on submit form.

Comment: This is a good option, you do not need to rebuild the entire page. Because I'm saving the input result to local storage, and if it's not empty (when rendering the screen) I have to change the text - `sharedPrefsGet() == null ? Text('ababababab') : Text('123123123')`,

Comment: If you want to update text in TextEditingController after your condition check, you can update its value like nameController.text = "123123123";

Comment: Okay, but if you go back to the option that you need to update the entire screen?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you - what do you mean by "you go back to the option" ?

Comment: You suggest a variant with clearing the form. And I need an approach with reloading the entire screen